# invalid credentials LDAP Symfony 6.*

Tags: php, symfony, ldap, ldap-query, symfony6

i want to Authenticat against an LDAP server , i managed to connect with the ldap server and also i managed to bind with the ldap user provider but i face a problem when i want to login

[SERVICE.YAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1S7b.png)

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
    tags:
        - ldap
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        -   host: ldap.forumsys.com
            port: 389
            #encryption: tls
            options:
                protocol_version: 3
                referrals: false
```

[SECURITY.YAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UZHX.png)

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
providers:
    
     my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: DC=example,DC=com
            search_dn: "CN=read-only-admin,DC=example,DC=com"
            search_password: password
            default_roles: ROLE_USER

firewalls:
    dev: 
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false 
    main:
        lazy: true
        
        provider: my_ldap
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: app_login
            check_path: app_login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: 'DC=example,DC=com'
            query_string: '(&(uid={user_identifier})(memberOf=cn=users,ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com))'
            search_dn: "CN=read-only-admin,DC=example,DC=com"
            search_password: 'password'
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_login
```

[DUMP on $passport var in LdapAuthenticator.php on Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/400rD.png)

[DUMP ON $this->adapter->createQuery($dn, $query, $options)->execute()->toArray() in Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8QO6.png)

[PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKxBk.png)

why it gives me this message error even i put the right credentials ?
*I use an online LDAP server [online LDAP server](https://www.forumsys.com/2022/05/10/online-ldap-test-server/)
*I work with Symfony 6.1.7

Comment: It's helpful if you paste your code into your question rather than use screenshots. This lets other people copy/paste your code so they can help you better.

Comment: I try it but they give me message error when i want share the question : " you write a spam "

Comment: Try to minimize the amount of code that you're pasting in. And it may be the link to the LDAP test server that makes it think it's spam.

Comment: i think is ok now